# Convert entire dom4j Element's namespace

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

If I have an XML element as such:

```
<First id="" name="">
  <Second id="" name="">
  </Second>
</First>
```

How can I use dom4j to convert the namespace to something like below? Is there a simple way?

```
<test:First test:id="" test:name="">
  <test:Second test:id="" test:name="">
  </test:Second>
</test:First>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a Java centric solution, DOM4J has support for traversing a document tree:

```
    Document doc = DocumentHelper.parseText(XML);
    final Namespace ns = Namespace.get("test", "urn:foo:bar");
    doc.accept(new VisitorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void visit(Element node) {
            node.setQName(QName.get(node.getName(), ns));
            // Attribute QNames are read-only, so need to create new
            List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
            while(node.attributes().size() > 0)
                attributes.add(node.attributes().remove(0));
            for(Attribute a: attributes) {
                node.addAttribute(QName.get(a.getName(), ns), a.getValue());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run an XSLT transformation:

```
  <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="test:{local-name()}" namespace="http://test-namepace/ns">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="test:{local-name()}" namespace="http://test-namepace/ns">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:transform>
```

I think DOM4J has methods to apply an XSLT 1.0 transformation directly, but you also have the option to use Saxon, which handles DOM4J as input and/or output alongside many other tree models.

Incidentally, (a) in your requirements example, the result document is ill-formed because it doesn't declare the namespace, and (b) it's not generally considered good practice to put all the attributes in the same namespace as the containing elements; I've given you a solution on the assumption that you have good reasons for this rather strange design.